# How to navigate in redux-action?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I need to navigate in redux-action. I'm try to implement an exit from an application. I always used react-native-router-flux before and not very familiar with react-navigation.

My code:

```
export const signOut = () => {
    const nav = NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: 'mainFlow', // It's navigation from drawer, so maybe I  // don't need to specify this routeName?
        action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'intro' })
    });
    return () => {
        try {
            AsyncStorage.clear();
        } finally {
            AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
            return nav;
        }
    }

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redux doesn't have access to navigation, But what you can do is.
For example you have an action in your component...

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getData();
}
```

and this actions needs to access navigation.
What you can do is, pass the navigation to it.

```
this.props.getData(this.props.navigation);
```

and in your getData action, you can just use the navigation object, for example

```
const getData =(navigation) => {
navigation.navigate('ToYourScreen');
...
}
```